# Unable to display results using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, visual-studio

I am trying to implement a comment feature on my page. I have an `itemID` 123. on that page, I would like to display the comments that people have posted about `itemID` 123. However as of now, I am unable to display these comments on my page. There are no errors in the console.

**Javascript:**

```
function mywall() {
    var url = serverURL() + "/viewwall.php"; //execute viewwall.php in the server

    itemID = decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["itemID"]);

    var JSONObject = {
        "itemID": decodeURIComponent(getUrlVars()["itemID"])
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        data: JSONObject,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (arr) {
            _mywallresult(arr); //success. execute _mywallresult()
        },
        error: function () {
            validationMsg();
        }
    });
}

function _mywallresult(arr) {
    var i;

    //for all the shouts returned by the server 
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        //append the following:
        //<b>
        //time of posting </b>
        //<br/>
        //the message
        //<br>
        //userid
        $("#wallcontentset").append("<b>" + arr[i].timeofposting + "</b><br/>" + arr[i].message + "<hr>" + arr[i].userid);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" id="wallcontentset"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried a `console.log(arr)`?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Hello! It says that arr is not defined.

Comment: ok do a `console.log(JSONObject)` as well. as of my previous comment, did you run that code within the success function?

Comment: try this as it is and let me know what output exactly you get in the console https://jsfiddle.net/Lar9dhmL/3/

Comment: @NevilleNazerane Hello! did what you're told and this was what the results produced: https://imgur.com/a/wiSnn

Comment: since you are using jQuery mobile, you are using a really old version of jqyery. i suggest you mention this version in your tags.

Comment: if my calculations are right your line 139 is `console.log(3, status, "There was some error:", message);` right? you can click on the 139 in your console and check if it takes you to this line

Comment: @NevilleNazerane It slipped my mind that I had forgotten to add in that line in. The console says: 3"parsererror" "There was some error:" SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at line 139

Comment: ok. then the issue is an issue in the way you are sending your `JSONObject`. That is `contentType`. try removing that line.

Comment: just try this code instead. https://jsfiddle.net/Lar9dhmL/5/. note that this is not recommended over what you have done. but just check if it works in the first place

Comment: @NevilleNazerane do i still keep the console log? sorry I'm kind of asking dumb qns bc json is something im not that familiar with

Comment: @NevilleNazerane it's still the same

Comment: in your web browser try `yourURL.com/viewwall.php?itemID=123233`

Comment: since your code is related to the php code as well, if you post the part of your php code that is accessing itemID and if you change your visual studio tag to php, you should get an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
success: function (response) {
    _mywallresult(response.arr); 
},
```